# how to change priority of offset() and multipliedBy() in snapkit

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I want to make the UIView's size: `height = (width - 100) * 0.5`, so the code like this:

```
view.snp.makeConstraints {
  $0.top.left.right.equalTo(0)
  $0.height.equalTo(view.snp.width).offset(-100).multipliedBy(0.5)
}
```

but the height result equal to `width * 0.5 - 100`,

how to change priority of `offset()` and `multipliedBy()`?

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, auto-layout first applies the **multiplier** and then the **constant**.

From Apple's docs:

[image]

To accomplish your goal, you'll need to use another view or, better, a `UILayoutGuide`.

Tell auto-layout you want the otherView/layoutGuide to be `viewWidth - 100`, and then you want view to be *that value* `* 0.5`.

Here's an example:

```
class SnapTestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a view
        let testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .orange

        // create a Layout Guide
        let vGuide = UILayoutGuide()

        // add the layout guide to the testView
        testView.addLayoutGuide(vGuide)

        // constrain the layout guide
        vGuide.snp.makeConstraints {
            // to bottom-left corner
            $0.leading.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            // height doesn't really matter (it's not visible)
            $0.height.equalTo(1)
            // width = superView (testView) width - 100
            $0.width.equalToSuperview().offset(-100)
        }

        // add testView to self.view
        view.addSubview(testView)

        // constrain testView
        testView.snp.makeConstraints {
            // 40-pts leading and trailing
            $0.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(40)
            // 100-pts from the top
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
            // height = layoutGuide height * 0.5
            $0.height.equalTo(vGuide.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.5)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to have `height = (width - 100) * 0.5` as on your description then your code should change to something like: -

```
    view.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.top.left.right.equalTo(8)
        let calculatedHeight:CGFloat = (view.bounds.width - 100) * 0.5
        $0.height.equalTo(calculatedHeight).priority(.required)
    }
```

And you can change priority using enum SnapKit's ConstraintPriority as explained on the official [documentation](http://snapkit.io/docs/) check on the sample code above.

Comment: `(view.snp.width - 100) * 0.5` throw exception: Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ConstraintItem' and 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Comment: @JoShin on your code is 'view' the main full view of the ViewController?

Comment: `UIImageView`, etc

Comment: I edited, and use view.bounds.width, that should fix the error but your imageView should ne having a width set to get desired result